# SQL Server PIVOT with CONVERT DATE

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008

I'm having a difficult time with PIVOT in SQL Server.

My table has the following data:

```
    saleDateTime        |  Value   |
------------------------+----------|
2018-10-30 14:29:01.000 |    87    |
2018-10-30 16:07:22.000 |    50    |
2018-10-30 16:19:36.000 |    80    |
2018-10-30 17:08:04.000 |    20    |
2018-10-30 18:09:16.000 |    35    |
2018-10-30 19:09:24.000 |    90    |
2018-10-31 13:09:41.000 |    12    |
2018-10-31 14:09:54.000 |    80    |
2018-10-31 16:18:12.000 |    30    |
```

What I need is the following result:

```
  saleDate    |  13   |  14   |  16   |  17  |  18  |  19  |
--------------+-------+-------+-------+------+------+------|
2018-10-30    |   0   |   87  |  130  |  20  |  35  |  90  |
2018-10-31    |   12  |   80  |  30   |  0   |  0   |  0   |
```

I need lines with the date of the sale, column headers with the hour that the sale was made and the values of the rows being the sum of the sales in that date and hour.

I couldn't wrap my head around the PIVOT function to solve this case. My table has only the `DateTime` value and I need to get two things from this column: the date and the time separately. Is there any way to use `PIVOT` with a `CONVERT` to make this work?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how to use [PIVOT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-2017) to get the desired result - converting `salesDateTime` to `date` to remove the time part, and pivoting by hour, calculated as `DATEPART(hour, saleDateTime)`:

```
declare @Sales table(saleDateTime datetime, Value int)

insert into @Sales (saleDateTime, Value) values
('2018-10-30 14:29:01.000', 87),
('2018-10-30 16:07:22.000', 50),
('2018-10-30 16:19:36.000', 80),
('2018-10-30 17:08:04.000', 20),
('2018-10-30 18:09:16.000', 35),
('2018-10-30 19:09:24.000', 90),
('2018-10-31 13:09:41.000', 12),
('2018-10-31 14:09:54.000', 80),
('2018-10-31 16:18:12.000', 30)


SELECT
    saleDate
    , ISNULL([0], 0) as [0]
    , ISNULL([1], 0) as [1]
    , ISNULL([2], 0) as [2]
    , ISNULL([3], 0) as [3]
    , ISNULL([4], 0) as [4]
    , ISNULL([5], 0) as [5]
    , ISNULL([6], 0) as [6]
    , ISNULL([7], 0) as [7]
    , ISNULL([8], 0) as [8]
    , ISNULL([9], 0) as [9]
    , ISNULL([10], 0) as [10]
    , ISNULL([11], 0) as [11]
    , ISNULL([12], 0) as [12]
    , ISNULL([13], 0) as [13]
    , ISNULL([14], 0) as [14]
    , ISNULL([15], 0) as [15]
    , ISNULL([16], 0) as [16]
    , ISNULL([17], 0) as [17]
    , ISNULL([18], 0) as [18]
    , ISNULL([19], 0) as [19]
    , ISNULL([20], 0) as [20]
    , ISNULL([21], 0) as [21]
    , ISNULL([22], 0) as [22]
    , ISNULL([23], 0) as [23]
FROM  
(SELECT cast(saleDateTime as DATE) as saleDate, Value, DATEPART(hour, saleDateTime) as saleHour FROM @Sales) AS SourceTable  
PIVOT  
(  
    SUM(Value)  
    FOR saleHour IN ([0], [1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8], [9], [10], [11],
    [12], [13], [14], [15], [16], [17], [18], [19], [20], [21], [22], [23])  
) AS PivotTable;
```

I added all hours, but you can remove the unwanted time slots if necessary.

Comment: That's it!!! Thank you so much! I didn't know about DATEPART, that makes it muich easier to get a specific part of a DateTime.
Thanks!